# Building a looping sequencer with AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioengine

I'm building a simple drum machine using the new AVAudioEngine capabilities in iOS 8, but am having trouble thinking through how I might build the looping mechanism.

It seems like the only way to do this is to have a rotating buffer of `AVAudioPlayerNodes` and have some sort of job that constantly schedules buffer playbacks in the future. Is this correct?

It would be nice if the nodes (and their buffers) only needed to be scheduled once. Then the nodes could all `reset`, then `play` again from the beginning every time the playhead reaches the end of the sequence.

I've tried the latter by creating an empty sample buffer, scheduling it at the end of the sequencer, and attaching to its `completionHandler`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
self.audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
self.instrumentNodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:12];

AVAudioMixerNode *mixer = self.audioEngine.mainMixerNode;

NSError *error;
if (![self.audioEngine startAndReturnError:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error starting engine: %@", error);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Started engine");

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Bleep_C3" withExtension:@"caf"];
    AVAudioFile *file = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:url error:nil];

    AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:file.processingFormat frameCapacity:(AVAudioFrameCount)file.length];
    [file readIntoBuffer:buffer error:nil];

    double sampleRate = buffer.format.sampleRate;

    AVAudioPCMBuffer *blankBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:buffer.format frameCapacity:0];
    AVAudioPlayerNode *loopingNode = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
    [self.audioEngine attachNode:loopingNode];
    [self.audioEngine connect:loopingNode to:mixer format:[mixer outputFormatForBus:0]];

    __block void (^schedule_loops)() = ^{
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 16; i++) {

            double sampleTime = sampleRate * (0.2 * i);
            double loopTime = sampleRate * (0.2 * 16);

            AVAudioPlayerNode *playerNode = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
            [self.audioEngine attachNode:playerNode];
            [self.audioEngine connect:playerNode to:mixer format:[mixer outputFormatForBus:0]];

            [playerNode scheduleBuffer:buffer atTime:[AVAudioTime timeWithSampleTime:sampleTime atRate:sampleRate] options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferInterrupts completionHandler:^{
                [playerNode stop];
                [playerNode reset];
                [self.audioEngine disconnectNodeOutput:playerNode];
            }];

            [playerNode play];

            if (i == 15) {
                [loopingNode scheduleBuffer:blankBuffer atTime:[AVAudioTime timeWithSampleTime:loopTime atRate:sampleRate] options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferInterrupts completionHandler:^{
                    NSLog(@"Looping");
                    [loopingNode stop];
                    schedule_loops();
                }];
                [loopingNode play];
            }
        }
    };

    schedule_loops();
}
```

Comment: You should add to the options when scheduling your buffer: AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferLoops.

[playerNode scheduleBuffer:buffer atTime:[AVAudioTime timeWithSampleTime:sampleTime atRate:sampleRate] options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferInterrupts | AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferLoops completionHandler:nil];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a loopable buffer either by reading a drum loop/beat from a file (as you are doing above) or create it programmatically.

Then schedule that buffer with a AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferLoops option and it will automatically loop for you.

You can have multiple player nodes, but I think of these in terms of tracks (like a single track in a 4 track recorder), i.e. for playing sounds at the same time.

You then schedule buffers on these player nodes.  So you could have a cymbal player node and bass drum player node etc, your buffers would be the sample sounds themselves.

I wrote a DTMF (phone tones) tone generator that plays two loop able sine wave tones at the same time, to do this I use two playerNodes each with a loop able sine wave buffer.

In my init method (createAudioBufferWithLoopableSineWaveFrequency: just fills the pcmBuffer):

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) AVAudioPlayerNode *playerOneNode;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) AVAudioPlayerNode *playerTwoNode;    
@property (nonatomic, readonly) AVAudioPCMBuffer* pcmBufferOne;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) AVAudioPCMBuffer* pcmBufferTwo;

[...]

    _playerOneNode = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
    [_audioEngine attachNode:_playerOneNode];

    [_audioEngine connect:_playerOneNode to:_mixerNode format:[_playerOneNode outputFormatForBus:0]];

    _pcmBufferOne = [self createAudioBufferWithLoopableSineWaveFrequency:frequency1];

    _playerTwoNode = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
    [_audioEngine attachNode:_playerTwoNode];

    [_audioEngine connect:_playerTwoNode to:_mixerNode format:[_playerTwoNode outputFormatForBus:0]];

    _pcmBufferTwo = [self createAudioBufferWithLoopableSineWaveFrequency:frequency2];
```

In my play method:

```
if (_playerOneNode && _pcmBufferOne)
{
    [_playerOneNode scheduleBuffer:_pcmBufferOne atTime:nil options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferLoops completionHandler:^{

    }];

    [_playerOneNode play];
}

if (_playerTwoNode && _pcmBufferTwo)
{
    [_playerTwoNode scheduleBuffer:_pcmBufferTwo atTime:nil options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferLoops completionHandler:^{

    }];

    [_playerTwoNode play];
}
```

My stop method:

```
[_playerOneNode stop];
[_playerTwoNode stop];
```

I can point you to my github project if it helps.

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could show the code for filling the buffers. Thanks.